# Style output of cookie inside text area

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I have a hidden textbox that stores data when a user click on product order button, and at the same time stores it inside a cookie.

So, when the user visit another page, lets say checkout page, they need to fill a form and the list of items they selected before will be listed inside a text area automatically.

Now it populates the data inside the text area but it is not a nice layout. Here is what it looks like.

```
Product1 Product2 Product3 Product4 Product5 Product6
```

How can I organize so that it displays like this?

```
Product1
Product2
Product3
Product4
Product5
..........
```

Below is my code.

```
<div id="hide" style="display: none;">
    <textarea id="myContent2" name="myContent2"><?php echo $_COOKIE['content']; ?> </textarea>
    <a onClick="addContent('myDiv2', document.getElementById('myContent2').value); setCookie('content', document.getElementById('myContent2').value, 1);">
    <br><br>
    <div id="myDiv2" style="font-weight: bold;"></div>
<a onclick="javascript:alert('<?php echo $_COOKIE['content']; ?>')">Here</a>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addContent(divName, content) {
    document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML += "<br>" + content;
   }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays) {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
}
function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length>0) {
    c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    if (c_start!=-1) { 
        c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1; 
        c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
        if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;
        var cookieContent =  unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        document.getElementById('myDiv2').innerHTML = cookieContent;
    } 
    }
}
getCookie('content');
</script>
```

Comment: you need to append the data with html break tag.

Comment: never store a customers shopping cart in a cookie. textarea is a form element why would you be displaying the customers products in it?

Comment: @Dagon because its a simple text order form. not like the advanced features that some pages have.

Answer (score 0):

just added the newline command for innerHTML "\n" at the product name. solved the problem.

thank you all